# If fprintf writes a string and fwrite writes bytes; then, for what is used fopen’s parameter “w” and wb?

Tags: c, file, save

I have the following code, if I change "W" for "Wb" it works identical,  Why?

```
void wrte (){
  //tpeDta roundLotSze[] = {65,66,67,68};
  tpeDta roundLotSze[] = {66,65,6767,75};
  FILE * fle = fopen(".//bse//fleNmber.dat", "w");
  fwrite(&roundLotSze,sizeof(roundLotSze),1,fle);
  fclose(fle);
}
```

It looks like the parameter for `fopen` doesn't work. Just using these functions change the behavior of writing data and the output.

What is the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429969/why-opening-file-for-binary-access-is-meaningless-on-unix-nor-the-for-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is how newlines are read / written.

On Linux or other UNIX-like systems, there is no difference between `"w"` and `"wb"`.  On Windows using `"w"`, writing a byte with the value 10 will result in two bytes with values 13 and 10 being written.

This is due to newlines on Windows being represented by both a carriage return (ASCII 13) and a linefeed (ASCII 10), while on UNIX-like systems a newline is just linefeed.

Comment: Thanks, pretty clear.